# Zend syntax explanation - %value% what does it mean?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I see syntax on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html

**The case**- what does %value% mean and doing?

```
  protected $_messageTemplates = array(
    self::FLOAT => "'%value%' is not a floating point value"
  );
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe someone could also explain why they are using `%value%` and not just the typical [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) `%s` placeholder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a placeholder that will be replaced by the field's value when displaying this error.

If a user enters `"ABC"` is this field, the error message will be `"'ABC' is not a floating point value"`

This is like printf's `%s` placeholders, in a more verbose and easy to use form. Validators can add their own placeholder variables, and it's easier to deal with `%value%`, `%somevar%` than with (positional) `%1$s`, `%2$s`, particularly for translators.

Comment: Thanks!Can you please show where does it happen in zend source code?

Comment: I find out :in Zend_Validate_Abstract $message = str_replace('%value%', (string) $value, $message);